# Как сохранить значение таймера?

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр, мобильная-разработка

Я начинающий. Нужно сохранять Textview todo (задание) и Textview chronometer (значение таймера обратного отсчёта). Задание сохраняется, а вот с таймером что-то не получается. Или как ещё можно осуществить сохранение значения, чтобы после закрытия и нового открытия приложения таймер продолжался. Как это осуществить? В чём ошибка?

Код:

```
package game.doit; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class StartGame extends AppCompatActivity {

    long duration = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24);
 final String TAG = "STATE";
private long backPressedTime;
public static Toast backToast;
 static SharedPreferences save;
CountDownTimer timer;
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "save";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_TODO = "todo";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER = "chronometer";
Context context;
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_game);
    context = this;
 

    //Массив
    String[] tasks = {"Не спать всю ночь", "Здоровайся с каждым прохожим", "Проведи день с родителями", "Выучи 10 новых иностранных слов",
            "Придумай 5 своих слов", "Улыбайся окружающим", "Пробежать 3 километра", "Сделай только 2 приёма пищи",
            "Сделай генеральную уборку дома", "Забудь про телефон на 24 часа", "Приготовь пирог", "Разговаривай на иностранном языке", "Придумай подробный сюжет для фильма"};
    // Вычисляем, сколько слов в массиве
    int tasksLength = tasks.length;
    //Генерируем случайные числа
    int rand = (int) (Math.random() * tasksLength);

    //Ставим задачу
    String task = tasks[rand] + " ";
    TextView todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);
    todo.setText(task);

    //Button BACK
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    Button buttonBack = findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);

    buttonBack.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartGame.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    });
    //


    //CountDownTimer
    TextView chronometer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
           
            String duration1 = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d : %02d : %02d", 
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(l), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l) - 
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(l)), (l/1000)%60 );
            chronometer.setText(duration1);
        }


        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(StartGame.this, EndGame.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

    loadText();
}


//System button Back
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartGame.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
//

  void saveText () {
      TextView todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);
      TextView chronometer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
      SharedPreferences save = StartGame.this.getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = save.edit();
      editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER, chronometer.getText().toString());
      editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_TODO, todo.getText().toString());
      editor.apply();
}
         void loadText () {
            TextView todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);
            TextView chronometer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
            SharedPreferences save = StartGame.this.getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
            chronometer.setText(save.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER, chronometer.getText().toString()));
        todo.setText(save.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_TODO, todo.getText().toString()));
    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveText();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    saveText();
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadText();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    saveText();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    TextView todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);
    TextView chronometer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    outState.putString("chronometer", chronometer.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("todo", todo.getText().toString());
         Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    TextView todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);
    TextView chronometer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    chronometer.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("chronometer"));
    todo.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("todo"));
    Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
}
}
```

Comment: зачем сохранять таймер обратного отсчета? Нельзя сохранить дату и время, к которому отсчет ведет?

Comment: Каким образом? Если можно поподробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: То есть идея такая: открыл приложение - получил задание на 24 часа - закрыл приложение - открыл приложение позже , например через 2 часа - таймер продолжает работать , осталось 22 часа.

Answer (score 0):

При сохранении задачи учитывай время на которое она сохраняется, а не какое осталось. Я бы сделал так
При сохранении задачb ставил бы такое время System.getcurrenttimemillis() + (время на выполнение задачи в миллисекундах), пусть это будет переменная endOfTask. Потом при повторном запуске приложения время на таймере я бы считал так: endOfTask - System.getcurrenttimemillis()

Comment: Я это сделал, но дело в том, что значение таймера просто статично висят в textView . То есть отсчёт не продолжается